# Regexp : Exclude list of several words

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to understand how to make a regexp that excludes a list of several "words" or "letter".
I want all except the words "excludedword-" and the "/".

With this regexp: `^\/test\/(?!excludedword-).*$`
`/test/a-b` Macth
`/test/a-b/c` Match  **but I don't want it to match**
`/test/excludedword-a-b` Dont match

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^\/test\/(?:(?!excludedword-|\/).)*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xTRNJe/1/). Your initial expression did not work as you had not alternation in it.

---

In `JavaScript`:

```js
strings = ['/test/a-b', '/test/a-b/c', '/test/excludedword-a-b']
rx = /^\/test\/(?:(?!excludedword-|\/).)*$/

strings.forEach(
    item => console.log(rx.test(item))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `[^\/]*` negated character class rather than a `.*` that matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible:

```
/^\/test\/(?!excludedword-)[^\/]*$/
                           ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/awgq9X/2) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%2Ftest%2F(%3F!excludedword-)%5B%5E%2F%5D*%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/test\/` - a `/test/` substring
- `(?!excludedword-)` - an excluded word followed with `-`
- `[^\/]*` - 0 or more chars other than a `/`
- `$` - end of string.